# Centos 7 sharp: Installation error: unable to get local issuer certificate

Tags: npm-install, cpanel, centos7, strapi, sharp

I want to install Strapi on a sharing hosting (Centos 7, Cpanel). I created node app via 'set up node.js app', uploaded my Strapi files without node_modules. Then in terminal executed npm install, but during installation got 'sharp: Installation error: unable to get local issuer certificate' error.

I tried:

-following these steps recommended by the hosting support:

npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/
npm config set strict-ssl false
npm install -g npm@latest
npm cache clear --force
npm install

-Installing via Yarn, got this:

error /home/uniwebs/strapi/node_modules/sharp: Command failed.
Exit code: 1
Command: (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
Arguments:
Directory: /home/uniwebs/strapi/node_modules/sharp
Output:

Still no luck. Any suggestions?

P.S: full npm error:

npm ERR! code 1
npm ERR! path /home/uniwebs/nodevenv/strapi/18/lib/node_modules/sharp
npm ERR! command failed
npm ERR! command sh -c (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)
npm ERR! sharp: Downloading https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.14.2/libvips-8.14.2-linux-x64.tar.br
npm ERR! sharp: Please see https://sharp.pixelplumbing.com/install for required dependencies
npm ERR! sharp: Installation error: unable to get local issuer certificate

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/uniwebs/.npm/_logs/2023-08-14T15_12_35_537Z-debug-0.log

Comment: Is there some of the error message missing????

Comment: I added npm error. And yarn output is full, yes. Output was empty

Answer (score 0):

Installing older versions of node and strapi would solve the problem. For me it was strapi 3.6 and node 14.x